# $.extend is not a function with angular SSR

Tags: jquery, angular, browser, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Getting Jquery error after running

```
npm run build:ssr
```

```
var oldMomentProto = $.extend({}, newMomentProto); // copy of original moment methods
                       ^

TypeError: $.extend is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:107980:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:106754:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:111273:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:106754:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:108478:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:106754:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:119093:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:106754:30)
    at C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:106797:18
    at C:\Users\Desktop\angularApp\frontend\ui\theme\dist\demoapp\server\main.js:106800:10

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
```

The error is coming because fullcalendar needs jquery.

Comment: Can you show your code of component and which line of this error comes in ?

Comment: in which angular component this comes in ?

Comment: I think I have one work around to this error, But before that tell me in which component this error comes in and also little bit explain me about your use-case.

Comment: I am not able to understand main.js and from which component the error comes. It is coming from dist/appname/server/main.js

Comment: thats okay. But Have you used jquery in your project or not ?

Comment: yes at many components import * as $ from 'jquery';

Comment: Okay. and this error comes when ? at build time or at runtime  of project ?

Comment: This server Error comes at build time npm run build:ssr or npm run serve:ssr            npm ERR! demoapp@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/demoapp/server/main.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232589/discussion-between-nupur-and-gaurangdhorda).

Comment: Try using `isPlatformBrowser` to not load/use jquery when doing SSR